# Using "this" to avoid cascading effects on all related DOM elements

Tags: jquery

Hello

Scenario:

In a table of results with rows that are created dynamically and there has to be a paragraph that upon clicking opens a panel. Naturally all have the same id or class name as they are produced dynamically so they should be referenced by "this" to avoid that on clicking on one paragraph all panels of all rows open.

This is what I have:

```
<script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#changetext").click(function(){
    $(".panel").toggle();
    $('#changetext').text("Click to close/Open");
    });    
});

</script>
```

In the CSS code I have made the panel by default to be hidden (display:none)

and the HTML chunk is:

```
        <p id="changetext">Click to contact this owner</p>

        <div class="panel">
        //block of code, a mail form for example
        </div>
```

So, at the moment I only have one row, so it works fine it does toggle the panel but as I will have more results, I am preseeing that if I click on one row, all panels of all rows will open. I know about the use of "this" but that is when the element that you click is the same than the element about which you want to make changes, like you click on a button and you want its value display change, but here there are two different things, one is a paragraph with an id of "changetext" and the other is a div, which is the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Naturally all have the same id*, **IDs in HTML must be unique.** You should use class selector instead.

Use something like this:

*HTML*

```
    <p class="changetext">Click to contact this owner</p>
    <div class="panel">
        //block of code, a mail form for example
    </div>
```

*Script*

```
$(document).on('click', '.changetext', function () {
    $(this).next(".panel").toggle(); //Use .next()
    $(this).text("Click to close/Open");
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vP728/)

Comment: You have solved it in your code when you figured out that you could use "next" so that while using "this" to reference actually the button or the pagraph it is the NEXT element that opens. So, yes, the id stuff I already wrote that it could not be used but your great contribution has been the use of NEXT.

Comment: I dont know who the bastard has been that has thumbed down the question as it was a very good one, very clearly whoever did it did not even understand it. It was more complicated than it sounded. It has been Satpal that has solved it. The reason people are lately thumbing down my questions is because of my nick Soviet Patriot CCCP-

Comment: @SovietPatriotCCCP, Don't use offensive words.

Comment: A word is only offensive if it does not apply, but if it does, it is a description, therefore, it matches the type of individual who maliciously hiding behind the screen thumbs down my questions because of my nick. Long live mother Russia and the Soviet Union.